# Form, Create and Update View for Many-To-Many Relationship

Tags: python, django, forms, model, many-to-many

This is my first question here and I am writing because I'm going mad with this, even after reading documentation and a lot of answers here. Thank you very much and sorry for my bad english!

I have these models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, blank = False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank = True, null = True)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False)

class ProfileCategory(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('profile', 'category')
```

Is this model correct?
I suppose to have already the database with the categories saved. I need a page where the user can create a new profile and choose the categories from a list of checkbox. Should I use two form in the same page, one for the profile and one for choose the categories or a single form? I think i need a ModelMultipleChoiceField for the categories.
I also need a view that display the same form already filled with the profile and the categories where the user can change the profile name, and add or remove categories.

Tell me if you need more information and thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You will get better help on here if you specify what is going wrong with the code fragment you have posted - have you tried creating the model?  What happened? What was broken / not behaving as you expected?

Comment: Yes, I created the model.
1) I don't know if the model is correct.
2) I don't know how to create a correct form for the ProfileCategory model
3) I suppose that the category field in my ProfileCategory model is a ModelMultipleChoiceField field but I don't know how to use this field in case of insert or update view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ProfileCategory` model is unnecessary here.  Use `ManyToMany` field to achieve the same result:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)

class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
```

Now you can edit profile with a single form as any other model.  The only thing you should to remember is to call [save_m2m()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) in case if you override the form's `save()` method.

**app/forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from app.models import Profile

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        widgets = {
            'categories': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        }
```

**app/views.py**

from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

```
from app.forms import ProfileForm
from app.models import Profile

class ProfileCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = ProfileForm
    model = Profile
```

**templates/app/profile_form.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

**app/urls.py**

```
from app.views import ProfileCreate

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^profile/create/', ProfileCreate.as_view()),
)
```

To update profiles use [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) with the same `ProfileForm` class and template.

**EDIT**: If you need additional fields in the `ProfileCategory` model then you can set it as intermediary model with [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) argument of the `ManyToManyField`.  To edit such models you have to use formsets.  Read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/), [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models).

Comment: Tank you very much! This works like a charm and I think this solution is better than mine. So if I don't have any field in my many to many relationship I don't need the 3rd module (ProfileCategory) in this case.. But if I have this 3rd model can I use the same solution using one form and save_m2m()? I am confused about this.. Can you link me an example please? Thanks.

Comment: With intermediary model things become much more complicated. See the updated answer.

Comment: It works! But in the front end, it shows `Category object` instead of the category's name.